# wget URL timeout implementation

Tags: bash, shell, wget

```
while read -r line; do

  wget -O /dev/null -S "$line" 2>&1 | grep -q -m 1 "Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT"
  if [ ${PIPESTATUS[1]} -eq 0 ]; then     # check greps return code
    echo "Yes"
    echo "$line" >> yes_urls.txt
  else
    echo "No"
  fi

done < text.txt
```

My wget is hanging on random URL's, is there any way to have it try to wget the URL for say 10 seconds max then if it doesn't work move on to the next $line in the text?

Thanks!

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you even *try* researching before asking?

Answer (score 0):

Something like a `--timeout` argument perhaps?

```
   --timeout=seconds
       Set the network timeout to seconds seconds.  This is equivalent to
       specifying --dns-timeout, --connect-timeout, and --read-timeout,
       all at the same time.

       When interacting with the network, Wget can check for timeout and
       abort the operation if it takes too long.  This prevents anomalies
       like hanging reads and infinite connects.  The only timeout enabled
       by default is a 900-second read timeout.  Setting a timeout to 0
       disables it altogether.  Unless you know what you are doing, it is
       best not to change the default timeout settings.

       All timeout-related options accept decimal values, as well as sub-
       second values.  For example, 0.1 seconds is a legal (though unwise)
       choice of timeout.  Subsecond timeouts are useful for checking
       server response times or for testing network latency.
```